# Why does switching back to a normal drive from a colon-lettered drive only work intermittently?

Tags: windows, windows-8, cmd.exe, drive-letter

With the `subst` command, one can create "drives" identified by any symbol, so this works:

```
subst *: C:\path
*:
```

The prompt then shows `*:\>`. Proof:

[image: proof of an asterisk-lettered drive]

`subst :: C:\path` also works, but the new colon-lettered drive can only be switched to with `cd /d "::\"` because `::` indicates a comment.

The interesting part is that typing `c:` (or another normal drive letter) to switch back after that only works intermittently. Sometimes the current drive changes, sometimes the command has no effect (no location change, no message). I can't seem to find a pattern of when it works and when it doesn't. This doesn't happen on any other drives, even ones lettered with unusual symbols. `cd /d "c:\"` always works, taking me back to my C drive.

I'm using 64-bit Windows 8.1.

What's going on here - why does the switching back only work some of the time?

Comment: I'm complete grossed out by this.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html: Undocumented behaviour: if a drive is substed using characters other than A-Z ($,#, :, !, 0-9) it will not appear in Windows Explorer or in the drives reported by SUBST.

Comment: I say attach a debugger to cmd.exe and monitor what executes when you switch drive from a lettered drive, then check again when switching from a star drive when it doesn't work.

Then report the bug findings to microsoft! :)